# How to fix SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 in woocoomerce checkout page

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce

My site was running fine. But suddenly in checkout page after entering address and clicking on the pay button it shows a error message **"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2"**. Though the order is placed but it is not redirecting to thank you page. I am unable to fix now. Can any one help please.

I have also tried deactivating plugins as I thought may be this issue is caused due to some plugin, but it didnt worked. **My Wordpress version:5.1.1, Woocomerce version: 3.5.7**

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brqfY.png)

Comment: Change theme to something tested like storefront and try the purchase process, if it works you know its something with your theme

Comment: I fixed it. Actually I made some changes wp_send_json() in wp function.php file and for that reason I was getting the error.